# Restrict access to webpage unless user is directed from PayPal

Tags: php, redirect, paypal

I am adding a "buy now" button to a website for a pdf download. For payments, I am using PayPal. When creating the "buy now" button, there is an option to redirect the user to a downloads page after they finish paying. Is there a way to restrict access to the downloads page unless the user is being redirected from PayPal? If not, is there a decent solution to, essentially, hiding the page so people can't find it?

Comment: Most places I've bought digital content with send me a unique link to my email address.  Is this not reasonable for your company as well?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that with PayPal but I will check it out.

Comment: While I've never implemented it, I do believe PayPal has a way to define a callback once a successful transaction has been made.  Here is some [light reading](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach would be nothing more than security through obscurity and offer you very little protection. Once the address of the page is known the referer can simply be spoofed and anyone could access it.

To access the page referer in PHP you would do this:

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

This will return a string that contains the HTTP referer.

Comment: PHP docs states - ["HTTP_REFERER ... is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted."](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: This is exactly what I stated in my answer and you felt it appropriate to re-iterate it in the comments and down vote me?

Comment: I would say that this answer offers you absolutely no protection.  While everything you had said is true, this isn't a solution to his problem.